# How do I make a simple Redstone Door with a lever that villagers can't go through?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a castle in Minecraft, but I want a door that villagers can't enter. So, I decided to make a Redstone door but everything I looked up on Google seemed too complicated.

What's the simplest Redstone door that villagers can't go through?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're having with making the door work?  You haven't really given us a whole lot to go off of.

Comment: @Frank it doesn't seem like the OP has made a door but rather is asking how to make a "simple" door, however even then the OP has not provided any details on what door they are looking for as a "simple" door to me would be an single iron door with a red stone trail between it and a switch

Comment: I had the same problem. I ended up using stone pressure plates. It's still possible that they will accidentally step on the plate and get inside but they no longer seek out my house at night. I play with a lot of mods so it's possible that it doesn't work in vanilla.

Answer (score 18):

The most simple door that a villager cannot go through is an iron door powered by a button. If you need to use levers, you will need to build a simple XOR Gate.

### Buttons

You will need:

- 1 [Iron Door](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door#Iron_Doors)
- 2 [Buttons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Button)

Put down the iron door and place a button on an adjacent block to the door on both sides. When you press the button the door will open momentarily, with just enough time to walk through.

[image]

### Levers ([XOR Gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit/XOR))

An XOR Gate is relatively simple to make, and allows you to open the door using levers on both sides of the door. I am using [XOR Gate Design D from the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit/XOR).

You will need:

- 1 [Iron Door](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door#Iron_Doors)
- 3 [Redstone Torches](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Torch)
- 4 [Redstone Dust](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone)
- 2 [Levers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lever)

> The XOR gate is useful for controlling a mechanism from multiple locations. When controls (such as levers) are combined in an XOR gate, toggling any control will toggle the XOR gate's output.

In our case, the output the XOR Gate is toggling is the iron door.

[image]

I chose this design because it is compact and simple (doesn't involve repeaters or pistons), but there are other [XOR Gate options](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit/XOR) to choose from if this one doesn't suit your needs.

---

With both of these methods you can open and close the door by flipping the lever or pressing the button. Villagers cannot get through becuase they cant interact with buttons or levers.

Quote from the "[Door](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Door#Iron_Doors)" page on the wiki:

> Since villagers cannot operate buttons or levers and zombies cannot break them, iron doors can be used to lock a house in a generated village.

Comment: Only issue with this is that it will can once opened you can't travel through and close it on the other side

Comment: Buttons and pressure pads work well too. Place a pressure plate on the side of the door you don't want the villagers on, but you can walk over to activate the door, then place a button on the other side. Alternatively two buttons or two switches also work.

Comment: @Flaunting Simplest I can think of to fix that would be two levers and a XOR gate but that might be a bit complex for OP.

Comment: @Ben Villagers can activate pressure plates.

Comment: @Studoku Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't past my mind to open the door from the other side. I have improved my answer with more detail.

Comment: @Caleb Read the comment. **Place a pressure plate on the side of the door you don't want the villagers on**

Comment: @Ben Whoops my mistake, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the commands /replace and /fill to make a neat door. just connect a button to a command block that puts an huge iron wall open/close by making an XOR gate with a command block on one side that fills the gate and another that replaces it with air. It is very simple if you follow the steps carefully.